# Saving score from other script to savescript

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to save the score at the end of the level, and am getting some errors.

Here is the score script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public float score;

    private IEnumerator Wait() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

    void TimerOfDeath(){
        if(score <= 0){
            GameObject.Find("TooLateGUI").guiTexture.enabled = true;
            GameObject.Find("Score").guiText.enabled = false;
            StartCoroutine(Wait());


        }
    }

    void Update () {
            {
            score -= 60 * Time.deltaTime;
            guiText.text = "Score: " + (int) score;
            TimerOfDeath ();
        }
    }
}
```

and the save script at the end of the level:

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
    using System.IO;

    public class Saving : MonoBehaviour
    {
        GameObject Score;
        void Start(){
             Score = GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<ScoreManager>();
        }

        void OnTriggerEnter( Collider other)
        {
            if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                GameObject[] NoOrbs;
                NoOrbs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Pickup");
                int count = NoOrbs.Length;
                if(count == 0){
                GameControl.control.levelcount += 1; //add +1 to levelcount


                    int newScore = (int)ScoreManager.score; //get score and put in newScore as int

                GameControl.control.score = newScore; //score from GameControl = this new score
                GameControl.control.Save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

2 errors: line11: cannot implicitly convert ScoreManager to UnityEngine.Gameobject, line 25: object reference is required for the non static field, method or property..

i'l add the save/loading script too just incase someone would need the info or could use the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public static GameControl control;

    public float score;
    public int levelcount;

    void Awake () {
        if(control == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            control = this;
        }
        else if(control != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat");

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
        data.score = score;
        data.levelcount = levelcount;

        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
            PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();

            score = data.score;
            levelcount = data.levelcount;

        }
    }
    public void overwriteSaveFile()
    {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            File.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat");
        }
    }
}
[Serializable]
class PlayerData
{
    public float score;
    public int levelcount;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is fairly simple, you declare your variable as a GameObject in this line:

```
GameObject Score;
```

when you actually want to store a ScoreManager. You need to change it to:

```
ScoreManager Score;
```

The second one is solved by changing

```
int newScore = (int)ScoreManager.score; //get score and put in newScore as int
```

to

```
int newScore = (int)Score.score; //get score and put in newScore as int
```

because "ScoreManager" is the name of the class, and the instance you are using was named "Score". Maybe check out what a static function is ;) I would also suggest that you rename your Score variable to something that makes it clear that its actually a ScoreManager. I'd usually just use

```
ScoreManager scoreManager;
```

or

```
ScoreManager myScoreManager;
```

Notice how instance names usually start with a lowercase character and classes with an uppercase Character. Thats why in the code "Score" is highlighted, stackoverflow thinks its a class when its actually an instance name

Comment: thanks mate that did fix the build errors now i still got to find out how i'l add score to an array and display all levels highest score but i've gotten further today than i thought i would thanks again

Comment: np, just try it out till you cant get further, then come back here :)

Comment: Hello again Tom, i've gotten a bit further since yesterday but i'm not sure if i'm doing it right and how to fill in the last holes.

i've asked a new question on this subject and would you mind taking a look at it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938533/highscore-display-system-for-multiple-levels