# highscore/display system for multiple levels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene set up with guiTexts: Level 1: , Level 2:, ... i have a working save/load system using serialization but i don't exactly know how to save the scores per level and displaying them in the guiTexts which are in a different scene. i also don't know how to test if what i have so far is currently working right.

here is the saving script that saves at the end of the level and gets the score from an other script and saves it to highscores arraylist which then is saved to Highscores arraylist in the GameControl script:

```
public class Saving : MonoBehaviour
{
    ArrayList highscores = new ArrayList();
    ScoreManager Score;
    void Start(){
         Score = GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<ScoreManager>();
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter( Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player") //when player hits the collider at end of the level
        {
                int newScore = (int)Score.score; //get score and put it in int in newScore
                int rawlevelCount = Application.levelCount;
                int dontCountMenus = 2;
                int levelCount = rawlevelCount - dontCountMenus;
                highscores.Insert(levelCount, newScore);
                GameControl.control.Highscores = highscores; //save current highscores to GameControl Highscores
                GameControl.control.Save(); //saveGame

            }
```

The GameControl script that should serialize the Array:

```
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public static GameControl control;

    public int levelcount;
    public ArrayList Highscores = new ArrayList();

    public void Save()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat");

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
        data.levelcount = levelcount;
        data.Highscores = Highscores;

        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
            PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();

            levelcount = data.levelcount;
            Highscores = data.Highscores;
        }
    }

[Serializable]
class PlayerData
{
    public int levelcount;
    public ArrayList Highscores;
}
```

none of these scripts give errors.

now what i need to find out is: how do i write the variables from the array to the correct GuiText  something like this?

```
guiText("Level1score") "Level 1:" + score from array position 1;
guiText("Level2score") "Level 2:" + score from array position 2;
```

etc until atleast 55 and leaving the ability to add more levels whenever i want to (hence why i'm using arraylist instead of normal array)

Comment: Usually you want to narrow down the problem to as few relevant code lines as possible, that way you get answers.

Comment: I am still lost with what you are trying to do.

Comment: let me update my question again. I thought since i am a beginner i should post all my code incase someone finds an other problem that i didn't realize, i also thought adding the full code could help other beginners reading this, i have had the problem of not understanding snippets of code i find or on how to implement these myself due to lack of understanding. but you are right, thank you for the advice

Comment: the scores are saved into the array and i'd like to write the variables inside to the number of guiTexts that i have set up in a unity scene ment for Highscores, right now there are 5 guiTexts(1 for each level) and after playing 5 levels i would want these 5 scores from each level in the correct guiText